# Rails 4 Bootstrap Search Form in Navbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I have some [rails-bootstrap-form](https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/rails-bootstrap-forms) code in a header partial that gets rendered in the Rails 4 application layout:

```
<div class="navbar-form navbar-right">
  <%= bootstrap_form_tag controller: 'devices', action: 'index', method: 'get' do |f| %>
    <%= f.search_field :search, hide_label: true, placeholder: 'Search' %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", :name => nil %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I want this search form to always perform a `GET` request on the devices controller's index action. The search doesn't actually link to the devices index url, it appends the search parameter to the current url like this: `/devices/1?search=foo`. Since it just appends to the current URL, the search works fine from `/devices`.

I thought that if I pass in `controller: 'devices', action: 'index', method: 'get'` to `bootstrap_form_tag` it would force the URL to rewrite, but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up stripping out `bootstrap_form_tag` and I went with a standard `form_tag`. I had to add the bootstrap form classes in manually.

```
<%= form_tag(devices_path, method: 'get', class: 'navbar-form navbar-right') do %>
  <%= search_field_tag 'search', nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Search'  %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: 'btn btn-default', :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

I thought the bootstrap-forms gem would save time, but it definitely didn't for the search.

Comment: agreed - standard form tag with class was much easier.